# CMake: How to pass preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, cmake

How can I pass a macro to the preprocessor? For example, if I want to compile some part of my code because a user wants to compile unit test, I would do this:

```
#ifdef _COMPILE_UNIT_TESTS_
    BLA BLA
#endif //_COMPILE_UNIT_TESTS_
```

Now I need to pass this value from CMake to the preprocessor. Setting a variable doesn't work, so how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot pass a macro to the compiler, macros are evaluated by the precompiler before they reach the compiler.

Comment: Sorry for being inexact! I'm refering to MACROS passed to make conditional compilation.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`add_definitions(-DCOMPILE_UNIT_TESTS)` (cf. [CMake's doc](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_definitions)) *or* modify one of the flag variables (`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, or `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<configuration>`) *or* set `COMPILE_FLAGS` variable on the target.

Also, identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation. Identifiers containing double underscore, too. So don't use them.

Comment: Can also be done from the command line a la `cmake .. -DCOMPILE_UNIT_TESTS`

Comment: @dantswain: That sets CMake cache variable.

Comment: To add a definition only to specific targets, use [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS). For example: `set_target_properties(target1 target2 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "COMPILE_UNIT_TESTS")`

Comment: Or [target_compile_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_definitions.html) in CMake 3.0

Comment: Ugh ... "organically grown" build systems without uniform support across platforms are really a pain. Never know which one is the right option. Besides, how do I express _undefining_ a preprocessor symbol?

Answer (score 22):

If you have a lot of preprocessor variables to configure, you can use [configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file):

Create a configure file, e.g., *config.h.in* with

```
#cmakedefine _COMPILE_UNIT_TESTS_
#cmakedefine OTHER_CONSTANT
...
```

Then in your [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization):

```
set(_COMPILE_UNIT_TESTS_ ON CACHE BOOL "Compile unit tests") # Configurable by user
set(OTHER_CONSTANT OFF) # Not configurable by user
configure_file(config.h.in config.h)
```

In the build directory, file *config.h* is generated:

```
#define _COMPILE_UNIT_TESTS_
/* #undef OTHER_CONSTANT */
```

As suggested by [robotik](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/3913817), you should add something like `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})` to your *CMakeLists.txt* file for `#include "config.h"` to work in C++.

Comment: @robotik suggests that you need `include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})` or else CMake will not bea ble to find the generated `config.h`.