# Alternatives/Tools for #define hell C/C++

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, buildconfiguration

In our C/C++ Project we use a configuration header (~1000 lines) that is full of #ifdef's and #defines

```
#if (defined(HW_1) || defined(SOME_TECHNOLOGY_SUPPORTED)) && defined(OTHER_TECHNOLOGY_SUPPORTED)
 #define SOME_FEATURE_AVAILABLE
#endif
```

In our build configuration we predefine some defines that are passed to the compiler. This results in different defines (like SOME_FEATURE_AVEILABLE) in our configuration header.

Since our configuration header is quite big, there is also a bit of a mess.

Are there any alternatives for this `#define` hell?

Or are there any tools that help to see in what case which defines are set.

We are developing embedded firmware so we can't replace conditional compiling by runtime if's.

Comment: On which system do you compile. For which operating system? Look for `autoconf`  and `autotools` ....

Comment: If you stick to ANSI C89 and ISO C++ 98, then you don't need any of them.

Comment: Still the compiler may be able to optimise away if conditionals if you define static const booleans.

Comment: I'd look for `cmake`, especially the `configure_file` command.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not in some cases making premature optimizations when using #define instead of runtime conditionals?

Comment: Since your buildsystem basically decides already what's possible and what not, can't you also let your build system take care of including/excluding certain sources? And for the headers: I seriously doubt you need to know if SOME_FEATURE_AVAILABLE is defined everywhere. You could start by splitting up the mega-header into multiple more focused ones.

Comment: I second the cmake suggestion. With cmake I have the defines already set by the build system also (in some cases) I even have cmake not include cpp and header files that would not be needed if some option is disabled.

Comment: I recommend `cmake`. It has a usefull command to manage defines:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/9640357/763394

Comment: Thanks for your answers. We are building with IAR (for target hardware) and Visual Studio (for simulation). I know cmake but we can't use it since it doesn't support generating IAR project files. We need them for debugging on the target hardware.

Comment: @H2CO3: If you can get away with sticking to ANSI C89 (equivalently ISO C90) and ISO C++98, that's great -- but then there are a lot of system-specific things you won't be able to do. For example, all of POSIX would be unavailable.

Comment: @KeithThompson unfortunately. But sometimes it'a just inevitable. I generally don't care about Windows and its POSIX-less and C99-lacking stupidity, but my current pet project is written in strict C89 for the sake of maximal portability.

Answer (score 1):

In case all your `#define`'s are in a single configuration file, you can try doing a preprocessor-only compilation and then finding all defined macros. E.g.,

```
$ gcc -DFEATURE1 -DFEATURE2 -E configuration.h | grep '#define'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about and consider C++ policy-based design (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) introduced by Alexandrescu in his book "Modern C++ Design".

Comment: I prefer "bridge" pattern to policy-based design: it achieves the same goal w/out templates or multiple inheritance.

Comment: I guess bridge incurs some runtime overhead (?). Policy-based design (using templates) does not. Multiple inheriance does not cause problems here, as you do not handle objects as base-class object (do not treat them polymorphically).