# Detect [[noreturn]] support by C++ compiler via CMake or preprocessor checks?

Tags: c++11, cmake

I'm working with some code that is supposed to support both C++11 and C++03. I would like to mark a function `[[noreturn]]` but since that does not exist in C++03 I'm trying to figure out how best to guard it with preprocessor symbols.

In this email thread, it's suggested to try to check whether an individual feature is supported rather than all of C++11:

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-February/053635.html

Todd Greer writes:

> You might consider using code from Boost's config subsystem. There's a list of dozens of macros they define to set what features are available in what compilers here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported
>
> --
>   Todd Greer
>   Principal Scientist, Affinegy, Inc.

However, I didn't find anything that seems to do what I want. (In the boost config stuff, or elsewhere.)

Does anyone know a way to do this directly with a C preprocessor trick, or know of an existing CMake module that detects this feature? (If not I guess I will try to kludge one together.)

Comment: Are you sure it's a C++11 feature? I thought it was a compiler-specific extension.

Comment: Clang has the macro `__has_cpp_attribute`, which you can use to check for a C++11-style attribute being available, but AFAIK, it's unsupported with the GCC.

Comment: @imallett: these guys aren't always right, but they claim it is part of C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes I guess I could check in the standard...

Comment: I just checked the GCC docs, it supports `__has_cpp_attribute` since 5.1: http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-5/changes.html

Comment: Since it's a standard attribute introduced in C++11, `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L` seems like a perfectly reasonable way to check for it.

Comment: @Nemo: and if a compiler supports C++11 but not all features of C++11?  Will `__cplusplus` still be the same value?

Comment: `[[noreturn]]` (and other attributes) is defined to not change the semantics of a program.  It simply gives the compiler the *hint* that this function does not return, which can remove warnings, optimize better, etc.

Comment: @Yakk: If you mark the function `[[noreturn]]` but return anyway, the behavior is undefined. (So you can always remove `[[noreturn]]` safely, but not always add it safely. Thus saying it "does not change the semantics of the program" is an overstatement, I think.) Of course, it is always safe to err on the side of omitting it, which I believe was your point...

Comment: @RemyLebeau: For all 0 of the compilers that implement `[[noreturn]]` but not the rest of C++11, the simple `__cplusplus` check will cause you to omit the attribute, which is itself perfectly safe.

Comment: @Nemo: My point is, not all C++11 compilers support the `[[noreturn]]` attribute (Embarcadero's Clang-based C++11 compilers [do not support it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Workaround_for_C%2B%2B0x_Attributes)). And not all compilers define `__cplusplus` as a language version number, but rather as a boolean 0/1 flag or as a compiler version number. So checking `__cplusplus >= 201103L` to see if `[[noreturn]]` is supported is not always a valid check.

Comment: There are very good reasons why a compiler may have `__cplusplus` defined for C++11 but not have all C++11 features. The only real way to do it _automatically_ is to prepare your automake/configuration subsystem to try to compile a small test that uses it -- if it succeeds it is available, otherwise it is not, and pass the results on to your program via macros (either directly as part of the configure scripts or as a generated #include file). I'm not sure how to do that with CMake...

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The reason why some compilers define `__cplusplus` as `1` is **exactly** because they're missing features. On those, you stick to C++98 and hope that still works. The fundamental problem here are C++-03 compilers which already have `[[noreturn]]` as an extension.

Comment: @MSalters: what about the compilers that define `__cplusplus` as a compiler version number instead of a language version number?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Same idea, they're all a lot below `199711L`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#ifdef __has_cpp_attribute
#  if __has_cpp_attribute(noreturn)
#    define NO_RETURN [[noreturn]]
#  else
#    define NO_RETURN
#  endif
#else
#  define NO_RETURN
#endif

NO_RETURN void myFunc()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I guess what I was thinking about after reading comments was, like what you have, but also an `#elif __cplusplus >= 201103L`, since that should also guarantee that the symbol exists I guess, even if `__has_cpp_attribute` does not

Comment: @ChrisBeck except when a compiler claims to be C++11, and isn't actually.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: checking for `__cplusplus >= 201103L` does not guarantee that `[[noreturn]]` is supported, especially in compilers that do not define `__cplusplus` as a language version number.

Comment: This is the save answer, but you will miss the compilers that do not support he nice __has_cpp_attribute like Microsoft's VS and some GCC 4.x.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the following CMake check:

```
include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)

check_cxx_source_compiles("
   [[noreturn]] void testFunc()
   {}

   int main(void)
   {
     return 0;
   }
"  HAS_ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN
)
```

Then you can pass HAS_ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN to [your config.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639449/cmake-how-to-pass-preprocessor-macros) and use this in your C++ code with an `ifdef`.

The advantage is, that you don't miss compilers that do not set the right _cpluplus variable or does not support the __has_attribute feature.

Depending on your setting, you might need to add flags to set the C++ mode (like -std=c++11 or c++0x). This can be done with CMakePushCheckState and modifying `CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS`.

Comment: I accepted the other one because it's what I actually did, but thanks for this answer also, it is helpful