# How to use CMake to generate C++ code when not using configure_file?

Tags: c++, cmake, configure

My [CMake](https://cmake.org) scripts generate some information that I want in my C++ code. The information is some text that I want the user to be able to see.

I know that I can define in my C++ code variables like: `@mySpecialVariable@`. If these variables are defined by CMake, then, when using `configure_file`, the source file is modified by whatever the value of `mySpecialVariable` is defined by CMake.

My problem is that I don't ever use `configure_file`. My build directory is separate from my source directory, but the source files never get copied (i.e., `configure_file`) from the source directory into the build directory.

Is there anyway to do this without using `configure_file`?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need to avoid using `configure_file`.  It doesn't have to put its result in the build directory, if that's the issue (and it seems like it might be?)

Comment: I can't use `configure_file` because the build system is rather complicated and I can't mess with the way it's currently being done.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here.  If nothing else, it'll give you something to google.  You want to set a preprocessor macro.  I've never used it for strings, but looks like that's doable:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639449/cmake-how-to-pass-preprocessor-macros

Comment: It is really hard to understand, what do you want **from us**. You say that you have *some* text-generation problem, but the only description of this problem is that `configure_file` could work... but it cannot for **unknown reason**. With so little info you ask us to suggest something. (It is not a blame that you don't describe why `configure_file` don't work for you. Your problem by itself is unclear.)

Comment: @jlconlin - I've been playing around with this a little.  It's *really* nasty to a do preprocessor string directly through `cmake`.  The issue is that you've got `cmake`, the `compiler`, and your `shell`, all interpreting `\\`` and `"`.  In other words, the escape characters have to be *just* right.  It makes escaping `'` in a perl one-liner (`'"'"'`) look friendly (and reliable).  And C/C++ preprocessor macros are very touchy to begin with.  And...if your build is already complicated, messing with compiler flags is not a great idea.  Directly setting *boolean* style flags is much easier...

Comment: @zzxyz Thanks for trying. I was trying various things as well with no luck. I think I’m going to try and tweak our build system and see if I can make it work that way.

Answer (score 0):

CMake 3.12 has a new function called [add_compiler_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html#command:add_compile_definitions) which should suit your needs.

Minimum Example:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(cmake_text)
set(MyCMakeVar "MySpecialText")
add_compile_definitions(CMAKE_TEXT="${MyCMakeVar}")
add_executable(cmake_text main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
#ifdef CMAKE_TEXT
    std::cout << "Cmake defined following text: " << CMAKE_TEXT << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "CMake did not define any text!" << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

The output on std out will be:

> Cmake defined following text: MySpecialText